# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching [bundle ID]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile

I always go with `automatically manage signing` when uploading builds to App Store Connect with Xcode and everything has worked great up until today.

After branching my project and adding push notifications when I try to upload a build I get these errors:
[image: screenshot of the errors saying: Provisioning Profile failed qualification. Profile doesn't support Push Notifications and doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement]

I've researched into this and looked at every single response on SO and elsewhere with no success.
For testing purposes, I even created a new empty project with no additional code and when I try to upload it, this is what I get:

[image: Another screenshot from a new empty project. The error message says: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching [app ID]]

Things I've tried:

- Deleting both the Apple Distribution and Apple Development certificates and generate them again
- Clearing `/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder and manually downloading the profiles
- Deleting Derived Data
- Clearing the project
- Disabling 'automatically manage signing' and enabling it again

With manual signing I get to upload the build but I can't wrap my head around why **the automatic option has stopped working**. I've recently updated Xcode to version 13 and no other significant changes have occured.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The same is happening to me, I didn’t find a solution yet

Comment: were you using Xcode 13?

Comment: same here Xcode 13, moved project to another team where I have developer role and now Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching com.blablabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688626#689590022

You need to add the "Access to Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate" permission to your account in AppStore Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Same issues with both my app where I have developer role. Everything signed well with my own apps.
I found simple solution: just build it on previous Xcode 12.1 and published successfully. Seems that it is Xcode 13 "feature"..