# Xcode 15: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode15

I have Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d), after successful archiving when uploading on app store getting below errors. I checked my provisioning profile and certificates are valid and  I am able to upload app on XCode 14.3.1.

**Error 1:**  `"No profiles for 'bundle Identifier' were found. Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'bundle Identifier'."`

**Error 2:**  `"Cloud signing permission error`

`You haven't been given access to cloud-managed distribution certificates. Please contact your team's Account Holder or an Admin to give you access. If you need further assistance, contact Apple Developer Program Support at https://developer.apple.com/contact/."`

[image]

**Below solutions I tried:**

1. Checked provisioning profile and certificates validity.
2. Solution mentioned here
   [Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching [bundle ID]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362808/xcode-couldnt-find-any-ios-app-store-provisioning-profiles-matching-bundle-id)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you were choosing manual signing to distribute your app, now in xCode 15 you have to choose Custom in "Select a method for distribution" screen as cleared in the below image:

[image]

, then you will be in the old distribution behavior.

Comment: I don't know how I can thank you. After spending hours on this problem I finally found your solution. thanks man

Comment: @RifatHossain, most welcome man, we are here to help each other.

Answer (score 3):

There may have been a change with Xcode 15. Now, it requires the account to have access to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" when uploading builds. You can ask the admin to update your permissions at https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users